# Apache HTTP2 with Tomcat AJP

Tags: apache, tomcat, https

I have the following AJP connector setup in Tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Apache then handles the TLS. However I would like to enable HTTP/2, so I tried this in the Apache .conf file:

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

Firefox and my own speed tests indicate that the connection is still running under http/1.1 though.

If I ditch Apache and use Tomcat directly:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               compression="on" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="private.key"
                         certificateFile="public.pem"
                          />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

The speed increase is significant, and Firefox reports HTTP/2.

Is the AJP connector preventing Apache serving up HTTP/2, or is there something else missing from my configuration?

Happy to continue with just Tomcat, but I'd like to compare the two like for like.

Incidentally, this logline from APR makes me wonder how much work APR is actually doing in this configuration (useAprConnector [false]):

```
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
```

Comment: We had the same problem. Coincidentally we found that our Apache instance was also using `mod_php`, which depends on `mpm_prefork`. This is causing Apache itself to be unable to use HTTP/2. After changing Apache to use `php-fpm` and `mpm_event`, HTTP/2 was working well for both PHP *and* the integration with Tomcat using `mod_jk`. See also [this question on StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/q/1056893/998138).

Answer (score 0):

first of all, compile apache httpd you must include this --enable-http2

like this

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-http2
```

In file httpd.conf you must add this line

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

apache httpd use http 2.0 via AJP port, the tomcat also http 2.0

[This I Login on httpd 2.0 and via AJP port to communicate with tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HASEZ.png)

Comment: We ended using Tomcat directly, without apache. So I can't confirm if this works, sorry. If someone else would like to comment.